# Good Blackener Product / Process for Aluminum and Stainless Steel

Tags: material-identification, metal, metalworking, material-sourcing

I am looking to replicate this type of finish on aluminum and stainless steel hardware:

[image]

This is Jax Iron, Steel, and Nickel Blackener on carbon steel (mild steel) with a Rustoleum 2x clear coat. I like this type of finish a lot but sometimes have to work with hardware that is only available in aluminum or stainless steel.

Edit: I've tried the Jax equivalent products on Aluminum and Stainless with subpar results, so I'm wondering if anyone else has tried something that works better, or found a specific method that gets good results when working with these.

What is a blackener product / process I can use to achieve similar results on these different materials?

Comment: @Joachim I've tried the Jax equivalent products for Aluminum and Stainless, they didn't work very well in my tests. Just edited to clarify that thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Joachim also most carbon steel blackeners will not work well on stainless, and vice versa. These metals have very different compositions as far as chemical processes like blackeners and patinas are concerned.

Comment: Presto Black SSB is advertised as doing what you describe.